# Question about Picard's theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $x'(t) = f(t,x) $ with $x(t_0) = x_0$. If $f$ is continuous on a rectangle $R$ and lipschitz with respect to second argument, then we know the initial value problem has a unique solution on some interval $J$.

Question: Is there an analogue of this theorem for the $\mathbb{R}^n$ case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you have $y'(t)=f(t,y(t))$, where $f:[a,b]\times \Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R^n$ and:

$\|f(t,y)-f(t,z)\|_\infty\le L\|y-z\|_\infty$,

then the same theory applies I believe.